# Syntax prevent user to sign up using their email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Greeting,

I trying to create an email signup system using Firebase and noticed that user getting error if their email address got syntax on it (example: xxx.yyy@gmail.com or xxx&yyy@gmail.com). But email such as (xxxyyy@gmail.com) is all ok.

Did I need to do anything at the server side to allow syntax to work?

Comment: If you want to validate if a user has written a valid email address, that usually happens on the client.

Comment: No you don't need to change that. That is the correct behavior.